# move currently running Jenkins build back into the queue

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Let's say that I have a job which has a run  currently running on one of the executors (e.g. run #1).  Is it possible to completely restart run #1 from a Groovy script?

Ideally, I would like to interrupt the execution of run #1, and move the run back into the build queue.  When the run is later pulled out of the build queue for execution, I want the run number to be #1 again, and I want the execution to restart from the beginning of the run (not the point where it was interrupted).

Is this scenario possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use groovy script to manage jenkins job. You can find a lot of handy scripts [here](https://github.com/cloudbees/jenkins-scripts) which can cover your scenario

Comment: Yes, I have searched through those scripts, but I don't think they cover my scenario.  It's possible that I missed one though.  Can you point me to the script that you think covers my scenario?

Comment: Well you wont get direct answer. You need to tweak a bit. https://github.com/cloudbees/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/cancel-builds-same-job.groovy this one cancels a build

Comment: Yes, I have seen that one showing how to cancel a build.  I think that's the easy part.  Moving the build back into the queue seems to be the hard part.